# Facebook user_groups permission not available for web apps?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions

I've created an app that requires showing the user a list of his groups on Facebook. I'm asking for the user_groups permission and all is working fine in development.

I submitted the app for review in order to make it live and my user_groups permission request was unapproved with the following message:

> The user_groups permission is only approved for apps that let people
>   use Facebook on platforms where Facebook is not already available. If
>   you're building an app on Android and iOS, for example, you won't be
>   approved for this permission. Web, Desktop and TV apps will also not
>   be granted this permission.

I just had to make sure I understand: Are no Android, iOS, or Web apps allowed to use this permission?? This sounds strange... Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you find a way to get a list of the user's groups *without* this permission?

Comment: (Three years later.)  It's a bit ironic that Facebook themselves *still* have documentation about calling this service via JavaScript, with no warning that "Oh, by the way, you'll never get any results from it."  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/group/events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is already in your question. No Android/iOS, TV App or Web App is allowed to use this permission, because there is a native Facebook client on those platforms (facebook.com counts as Facebook client) so the user can just use groups directly in the native client.

I believe all those group autoposter Apps made them do this. `user_groups` was mostly used for spamming groups.

Comment: I think the question behind the question is how do we get a list of the user's groups *without* this permission?

Comment: the answer to that questions is easy: you don´t. that´s EXACTLY what the permission is for, why would they even have that permission if it would be possible without it?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this relevant article:

http://sendible.com/insights/how-the-new-facebook-api-changes-affect-posting-to-groups/

Although you can't get a list of users groups, you can still post to a group if you have the groupid and publish_actions rights.